# Let $X$ be a random variable with Binomial distribution and let $Y=n-X$. Calculate $ρ(X, Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable with Binomial distribution and let $Y=n-X$. Calculate $ρ(X, Y)$

I have the following:

$$E(X)=np,\, Var(X)=np(1-p),\, E(Y)=n(1-p),\, Var(Y)=np(1-p)$$

I don't know if it's right. But $Cov(X, Y)$ is missing, which should be calculated as $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: $Y$ is a linear function of $X$, and so, $\rho(X,Y)=-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a little easier to use the other expression, $Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))]$. Then, since $Y = n - X$ and $n$ is fixed, that simplifies very quickly into $Cov(X,Y) = -Var(X)$. From there, the rest should be simple.

Comment: Indeed.  $\mathsf{Cov}(X,n-X)=-\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)$ .